# Linq - How to query specific columns and return a lists

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write a linq query that will only return certain columns from my entity object into a list object.

Below is my code which produces an error(can't implicitly convert a generic list of anonymous types to a generic list of type TBLPROMOTION):

```
IQueryable<TBLPROMOTION> matches = webStoreContext.TBLPROMOTION.Include("TBLSTORE").Include("LKPROMOTIONTYPE");

List<TBLPROMOTION> promotionInfo = null;

promotionInfo = (from p in matches
                orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
                select new { p.EFFECTIVE_DT, p.EXPIRE_DT, p.IS_ACTIVE, 
                p.PROMOTION_DESC, p.PROMOTION_ID, p.PROMOTION_NM }).ToList();
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this. I do not want to do a "select p" in this case and return all the columns associated with the query.

thanks in advance,
Billy

Comment: what is "matches" ? is it an IEnumerable<TBLPROMOTION> ?

Comment: sorry, added the matches bit to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you do `var promotionInfo = ()` and get a list of anonymous types?

Comment: In the end i had to go with the anonymous types.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, basically you can not cast an Anonymous type to a known type like TBLPROMOTION.

ofcourse, you can say `var promotionInfo =` and then get an `IEnumerable<{Anonymoustype}>` and use that to do, what you were wanting to do with `promotionInfo`.

Also, personally I prefer the **Fluent** version of a linq query, easy on the eyes, good programming diet, at least for me :)

```
var promotionInfo = matches
                .OrderByDescending( p => p.PROMOTION_NM)
                .Select( p => new { p.EFFECTIVE_DT, 
                                p.EXPIRE_DT, 
                                p.IS_ACTIVE, 
                                p.PROMOTION_DESC, 
                                p.PROMOTION_ID, 
                                p.PROMOTION_NM})
                .ToList();
```

Comment: going to go with the anonymous type solution.  I gave you a mark since this did help point me in the right direction.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving from a L2E query to a Type already defined, you may need a step between.  I haven't tried to compile this but something like:

```
   List<TBLPROMOTION> promotions = new List<TBLPROMOTION>();
```

var results = from p in matches
       orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
       select new
       {
           p.EFFECTIVE_DT,
           p.EXPIRE_DT,
           p.IS_ACTIVE,
           p.PROMOTION_DESC,
           p.PROMOTION_ID,
           p.PROMOTION_NM
       };

```
   foreach (var v in results)
   {
       promotions.Add(new TBLPROMOTION(v.EFFECTIVE_DT, v.EXPIRE_DT, v.IS_ACTIVE, 
       v.PROMOTION_DESC, v.PROMOTION_ID, v.PROMOTION_NM));
   }
```

Based on the comment below, you might try something like:

```
    foreach(var v in results)
    {
        TBLPROMOTION temp = new TBLPROMOTION();
        temp.EFFECTIVE_DT = v.EFFECTIVE_DT;
        temp.EXPIRE_DT = v.EXPIRE_DT;
        temp.IS_ACTIVE = v.IS_ACTIVE
        // Assign Other Properties
```

```
    promotions.Add(temp);
}
```

.......
Sorry: Just read the addition to the top.

Are you sure that none of the fields you're leaving out (instead of saying "select p") are required for a TBLPROMOTION object?  Also, sense your TBLPROMOTION object is going to have properties (and therefore memory allocated) for those skipped fields, why not just use an annonymous type or set up a helper class that contains only your needed properties?

Comment: Sorry, this would not compile for me.  I get an error stating that TBLPROMOTION doesn't have a constructor that takes 6 arguments.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to instatiate the object first?

Comment: going to go with the anonymous type solution.  Had to give you a mark for all your help, but another person gave that answer long ago.  Was just hoping i didn't have to go that route.  Thank you for you help and time.

Answer (score 1):

@Billy, following code worked for me.

```
List<TBLPROMOTION> promotionInfo = 
                      (from p in matches
                       orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
                       select new TBLPROMOTION(p.EFFECTIVE_DT, p.EXPIRE_DT, p.IS_ACTIVE, 
                                       p.PROMOTION_DESC, p.PROMOTION_ID, p.PROMOTION_NM)
                      ).ToList();
```

Comment: Although the question is old but I found it helpful so thought of adding my answer for other users. The idea of using contructor came from answer given by @matt-dearing

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
 select new TBLPROMOTION {.....
```

instead of

```
 select new {.....
```

Comment: This produces a syntax error saying "Can't initialize type TBLPROMOTION with a collection initializer because it does not implement type IEnumerable".

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TBLPROMOTION> promotionInfo = null;

promotionInfo = (from p in matches
                orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
                select new TBLPROMOTION { COL1 = p.EFFECTIVE_DT, COL2 = p.EXPIRE_DT, COL3 = p.IS_ACTIVE... }).ToList();
```

Where COL1, COL2, ... are the names of the properties on `TBLPROMOTION` you wish you populate.

Comment: That will fail at runtime in L2E; you can't instantiate entity types with initializers, only POCOs or anonymous types.

Comment: Tried this and failed at runtime as craig just stated.

Comment: I thought TBLPROMOTION was a POCO and matches contained the Entity Type. After the question's update I see that is not the case.

Comment: Tried this and failed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subset of the table you have 2 options:

- @Fredou mentioned select new TBLPROMOTION{...}
- other way is to create a custom DTO which has the exact properties & select them instead like:

  List promotionInfo = ...
                            select new TBLPROMOTION_DTO{
                               Effective_dt = ...
                            }

HTH